# Probability density function for urn problem

Tags: probability

An urn contains $4$ red balls, $1$ white balls and $2$ green balls. Two balls are drawn at random and without replacement. Let the random variable $X$ be the
number of red balls.

**Thoughts**: I surmise that there are three possible values for $x \in X$
where $X = {0,1,2}$. Then

$P(0) = (3/7)*(2/6)$

$P(1)= (4/7)*(3/6) $

$P(2)=(4/7)*(3/6) $.

The problem is that these respective probabilities don't seem to add up to $1$, so my question is where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 red balls and 3 non-red balls. Two are drawn at random without
replacement. The number of red balls drawn is $X.$ The random variable $X$
has a hypergeometric distribution. Look in your text for the formula
in terms of binomial coefficients (combination numbers).

In R statistical software the distribution can be computed as follows:

```
x = 0:2;  pdf = dhyper(x, 4, 3, 2)
cbind(x, pdf)
     x       pdf
  ## 0 0.1428571
  ## 1 0.5714286
  ## 2 0.2857143
```

For example,

$$P(X = 0) = \frac{{4 \choose 0}{3 \choose 2}}{{7 \choose 2}} = \frac{3}{21} = 0.1428571.$$

Alternatively, $P(N_1N_2) = P(N_1)P(N_2|N_1) = (3/7)(2/6) = 6/42 = 3/21,$
where $N_i$ means 'non-red' on $i$th draw.

So you have that one correct. Check the other two.

Comment: Brilliant thanks.

Comment: Thanks. @H.H.Rugh correctly points out (+1) that the 2nd is in error.
$P(\text{1 R}) = P(R_1N_2) + P(N_1R_2) = \dots .$

Answer (score 2):

Your method is ok, but for $P(1)$ you may simply take the ball in the opposite order (so a factor 2 is missing).

Comment: Ah yes thank you!!